# Weighted exercises for lower abs

Tags: exercise, abdominals, weights

Even at 15+% bodyfat, I've been able to get my upper abs to show clearly by doing weighted exercises: Cable crunches and weighted russian twists[1]. Looking back on it, I'd even say it wasn't that hard.

But still no lower abs. Those are harder for everyone, *they* say, and take lower bodyfat % than the upper abs. Since I've gotten such good results with weighted exercises to make the upper abs stand out, I'm looking for some similar options that target the lower abs. With weight.

How about it?

---

Footnote 1: For cable crunches, I'm up to 4 sets of 20 reps, working up from 70lbs to 90lbs as the sets go. For russian twists I'm currently doing 60 reps holding a 15lb weight. Since doing this for a few weeks, I'm really noticing results in my upper abs and obliques. It's easy/quick enough that I have no problem adding those exercises on 3-6 times a week. The 15% bodyfat number is where dexascan currently shows me.

Comment: Cliche but true: abs are made in the kitchen. You already have lower abs, you just have fat covering them.

Comment: And supposedly upper abs don't start to show until you get sub 13-14% bodyfat. Yet at 15%+, I've already got well visible upper abs, which have come in strongly as I've done weighted exercises. Cutting fat % reveals abs, but there still need to be abs to be revealed, and if you develop them, they show up sooner. Hence the question.

Answer (score 6):

You can't target the lower abs, as there are no distinct upper and lower ab muscles, it's all just rectus abdominis, and you can't spot reduce fat either.

Expect to need to get below 10% body fat for defined lower abs to be visible.